# Jquery form submit & textbox validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form.

The form has a textbox and a submit button, that's all.

I want the button to validate that the textbox isn't empty/blank before causing the page to trip; before posting the page.

1) if button clicked then if textbox is blank then change textbox background color & don't post the page back to the server.

2) if button clicked then if textbox is not empty post the page back to the server.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the question? You stated what you want, but not any description of your problem. Have you done research on how to validate a form?

Comment: Why not use the built in validation features of MVC including client and server side validation using validation attributes applied to a view model property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

```js
$('form').submit(function(){
  $('#id1').removeClass('errorField');
  var in1 = $('#in1').val();
  if (in1==""){
    $('#id1').addClass('errorField').focus();
    return false;
  }
  
});
```

```css
.errorField{background:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="another_php_file.php" method="post">
  <input id="in1" name="in1" type="text" />
  <button id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

---

You may already know this, but JIC: Where the form gets posted back to depends on the contents of the `action=` attribute on the form tag.

```
<form action="sumother_php_file.php" method="post">
```

Will send the form to a PHP file called `sumother_php_file.php`

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Will post the form to itself *(You would add PHP code between `<?php //tags ?>` to manage the question of whether the variable `$_POST['in1']` `isset` or not)*

Comment: The question isn't tagged PHP, and I really doubt they need an HTML tutorial.